# What is the difference between ConfigurationManager class and Settings class?

Tags: c#, configuration, settings

What is the difference between ConfigurationManager class and Settings class ?

I would like to load settings from a configuration file placed in the same folder than my executable. What should I use?

Thank you,

Comment: What kind of config file is it? app.config or your own?

Comment: @Oskar Kjellin I use the app.config file and the settings properties from Visual Studio. In my code I use Settings.Default.ConnectionString to get my values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Configuration is what you want. The Settings class is for per-user, editable settings. (as opposed to application-wide configuration)

Comment: Then what should I use between OpenExeConfiguration, OpenMachineConfiguration, OpenMappedExeConfiguration, OpenMappedMachineConfiguration methods of the ConfigurationManager class?

Comment: Depends on what kind of info you are storing, and whether you can include it in appSettings of the app.config/web.config. If you can, then "none of the above"